# How to calculate the average of a column with DataFrame?

Tags: python, numpy, dataframe

I want to calculate the average of a column with DataFrame.

For example the 4th column.
I use this code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(16).reshape(4,4))
list1= data.iloc[:, 3:4]
averageNum=np.mean(list1)
print(averageNum)
```

But the output is:

```
   3    9.0
dtype: float64
```

Why the output likes this?

In fact,I just want to get `9.0`,so how to get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) for select 4 column by position and then use `mean`:

```
averageNum = data.iloc[:, 3].mean()
print(averageNum)
9.0
```

Your solution return one column `DataFrame`, solution is use [`DataFrame.squeeze`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.squeeze.html) for `Series`:

```
averageNum = data.iloc[:, 3:4].squeeze().mean()
print(averageNum)
9.0
```

Answer (score 0):

If your 4th column has an index say 'column4' then you could just do -

```
mean_of_column = df['column4'].mean()
```

Functions like `iloc` get you the indices and thereby can be extremely slow when you have large amounts of data. **Its much better and faster if you could think of the operations you want to do in terms of vectors.** There are several inbuilt functions that i must insist you use like `mean` for example. I suggest you make yourself more familiar with [pandas library](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html)(*10 min intro to pandas for starters*) by actually spending some time with the diocs or any related blogs or talks, rather than looking up everything you want to do on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Given your data, how about

```
averageNum = data.iloc[:, 3].mean()
```

This locates the 4th column of `data`, which is a `pandas.Series`, whose mean is 9.

`print(averageNum)` shows `9.0`.

Comment: Thanks,this is helpful!